# Increase too-tight icon spacing in NSOutlineView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsimage, nsoutlineview, spacing

I'm writing a Cocoa application that displays the contents of an archive file in an [NSOutlineView](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOutlineView_Class/). I provide custom icons for an [NSBrowserCell](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBrowserCell_Class/) in the outline column, but I haven't been able to get the spacing quite right — the folder icon always appears too close to the disclosure triangle, as shown below. (FWIW, [Versions](http://versionsapp.com/) and [BetterZip](http://macitbetter.com/) both display similar data without the spacing issues.)

[NSOutlineView-icon-spacing http://img.skitch.com/20090918-tgfjh9x8dhgqxqnb2su8fby4ng.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20090918-tgfjh9x8dhgqxqnb2su8fby4ng.jpg)

Since only folder icons will have this problem, I really only care about fixing the spacing in that  context. (NOTE: I'm already caching the icons for reuse, so I have no problem with manipulating the folder image if necessary, since it will only happen once anyway.) I'm not sure if there's something I can adjust in the NSBrowserCell instance, but I haven't found anything that works yet, not for lack of trying.

---

For the curious, [JarScan](http://inetfeedback.com/jarscan) is a handy (free) command-line tool for locating Java classes within JAR files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "outline table column" (see [`-[NSOutlineView outlineTableColumn]`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOutlineView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOutlineView/outlineTableColumn)) is the [NSTableColumn](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableColumn_Class/) that draws the triangle and left padding as needed to display the hierarchy. The default cell for displaying table content is an [NSTextFieldCell](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextFieldCell_Class/). To increase the spacing you see, you have to do the drawing in a custom NSTextFieldCell subclass. The spacing is achieved by drawing your image with an x offset. (The outline view will draw the disclosure triangle regardless of which NSCell subclass is used.)

Note that you may have to override the following methods to draw correctly when the cell can be typed in, selected for editing, and the tooltip:

- [`-[NSCell editWithFrame:inView:editor:delegate:event:]`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSCell_Class/Reference/NSCell.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCell/editWithFrame:inView:editor:delegate:event:)
- [`-[NSCell selectWithFrame:inView:editor:delegate:start:length:]`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSCell_Class/Reference/NSCell.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCell/selectWithFrame:inView:editor:delegate:start:length:)
- [`-[NSCell expansionFrameWithFrame:inView:]`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSCell_Class/Reference/NSCell.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCell/expansionFrameWithFrame:inView:)

By default your custom text rects will be ignored by the text field and these will draw oddly.

Comment: Thanks, good suggestion. I found the idea to use NSBrowserCell on CocoaDev.com and hadn't considered this approach. Happily, a quick search turned up Apple's **ImageBackground**  sample code http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/ImageBackground/ and specifically the `ImageAndTextCell.m` file. It implements everything but the tooltip (which I don't need right now anyway) and handles some odd drawing behaviors I wouldn't have thought to account for. Jackpot, and hooray for code reuse!

Comment: BTW, I added this finding to http://cocoadev.com/index.pl?IconAndTextInTableCell as well.